# Can DB2 DDL be generated using the IBM.Data.Db2 library

Tags: db2, ddl

I'm new to Db2 and need to generate DDL for an existing table but don't have access to any tools.  Is it possible to do this through the IBM.Data.DB2 library?  I can get a datareader but only the field name is available.  I work in a very restrictive environment hence the no tools statement.  I don't know what operating system is used on the server.  I'm a c#\vb.net developer and can execute commands of type text and stored procedures; however, creating stored procedures is very limited.  I've done this sort of thing with Sql's SMO library but am not well versed with IBM.Data.DB2.

Comment: To find out about your Db2-server platform, (which you always need to know when working with Db2), either ask the people who manage the Db2-database, or edit your question with the result of the query `SELECT VERSIONNUMBER FROM SYSIBM.SYSVERSIONS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
            using (DB2Command dB2Command = new DB2Command($"SELECT * FROM {database}.{tableName}", dB2Connection))
            {
                dB2Command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                using (DB2DataReader dB2DataReader = dB2Command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = dB2DataReader.GetSchemaTable();
                    foreach(DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"ColumnName: {dataRow.Field<string>("ColumnName")}\nColumnSize: {dataRow.Field<int>("ColumnSize").ToString()}\nNumericPrecision: { dataRow.Field<Int16>("NumericPrecision").ToString()}\nNumericScale: { dataRow.Field<Int16>("NumericScale").ToString()}\nDataType: {dataRow.Field<DbType>("ProviderType").ToString()}");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: A result-set is not DDL, as understood by most practitioners, because it lacks details that DDL normally contains, such as keys, constraints, foreign keys, indexes, tablespaces etc. But if it meets your needs then fine, although it means your question was badly phrased.